# Delete records from table for users that has another record in the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following MANY_2_MANY table `users_categories`:

```
user_id | category_id
----------------------
   1    |  138
   1    |  1262
   2    |  1262
   3    |  1262
```

I need to delete all records with `category_id = 1262` for users that have both records - `category_id = 138 and 1262` So, in the mentioned example, it must delete the following record:

```
   1    |  1262
```

As the result, after query execution, the table must look like:

```
user_id | category_id
----------------------
   1    |  138
   2    |  1262
   3    |  1262
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM users_categories
WHERE category_id=1262 
AND user_id IN 
    (SELECT user_id 
     FROM users_categories 
     WHERE  category_id in (138,1262)
     GROUP BY user_id 
    HAVING count(DISTINCT category_id) =2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `exists`:

```
delete from user_categories uc
where category_id = 1262 and
      exists (select 1
              from user_categories uc2
              where uc2.user_id = u.user_id and uc2.category_id = 138
             );
```